# Can't get fixed table header to work, need scroll in x and y direction?

Tags: css, html-table

This is killing me and I've read so many stack overflow threads on it but I just can't figure it out. I've got a table that needs to scroll in the x and y direction, I have this part working. The trouble I'm having is getting the header to be fixed so when people scroll down, they can still see what each column is. Currently, I have `table-layout: fixed` because I would like the widths to be the same for each cell in `th/td`. The rows are derived dynamically with JS (the user clicks stuff on a map and it generates the rows to append to the table). If I do anything with `thead` or `tbody` the column width I have set for `th/td` is no longer respected. If I put `position: fixed` in `thead` it overflows the div, even if I set `overflow: auto` on `#table`.

I can do a jQuery solution if needed, though I really do not want to implement any more plugins.

HTML:

```
<div id="attribute-table">
    <button id="selectPatches">Select Patches</button>
    <button id="clearSelection">Clear Selection</button>
    <span id="featureCount">No features selected</span>
    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Point</th>
                    <th>Patch Number</th>
                    <th>Is Developed?</th>
                    <th>Crop Type</th>
                    <th>Crop Residue (%)</th>
                    <th>Canopy Over 12' (%)</th>
                    <th>Deciduous Canopy (%)</th>
                    <th>Coniferous Canopy (%)</th>
                    <th>Shrub Cover (%)</th>
                    <th>Shrub Stem Density (%)</th>
                    <th>Grass Cover (%)</th>
                    <th>Forb Cover (%)</th>
                    <th>Forb Protective Cover (%)</th>
                    <th># of Forb Species</th>
                    <th>Bare Ground (%)</th>
                    <th>Herbaceous Height > 8"</th>
                    <th>Coarse Habitat Type</th>
                    <th>Fine Habitat Type</th>
                    <th>Quail Habitat</th>
                    <th>Observation Date</th>
                    <th>Observation Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table-data"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="attrTable-handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
</div>
```

This CSS causes the widths of the cells to get all wonky and nothing lines up right (header still isn't fixed with this CSS anyway):

```
#attribute-table {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 250px;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    top: auto !important;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 31;
}

#attrTable-handle {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 0;
}

#attribute-table #featureCount {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#table {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#table table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#table thead {
    display: block;
}

#table tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

#table td, #table th {
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#table th {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've found `overflow: auto` must be set on `#table` to keep the table heading from overflowing the div and make scrolling work appropriately. I do not want to put `overflow: auto` on `#attribute-table` as I need the buttons and such to stay fixed at the top. Only the table should be scrollable.

If I remove `#table thead` and `#table tbody` styles, my table looks like this, but the header isn't fixed. I want the table to look exactly like this, but I just need that header to be fixed...
[image]

Comment: Why don't you put the scroll only in the tbody?

Comment: @Liora Haydont I can't do that because the table headings overflow the div. I need to be able to scroll in the x direction as well as the y.

Comment: Set a fixed height for the tbody (the height that the table - the header should have), so that it won't overflow, and then set overflow:auto to the tbody

Comment: @LioraHaydont I don't think I understand what that would do. The reason I have overflow set on `#table` instead of `tbody` (well, I have it set on tbody also which doesn't seem to do anything) is because the table is both wider and taller than the div. If I'm not mistaken, setting overflow exclusively on tbody will not stop the table from overflowing in the x-direction in the header (`thead`).

Comment: Hum, I didn't think about that. Then you should set overflow-x auto to the table and overflow-y auto to the tbody

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. In order to get the header fixed I'd have to add `position: fixed` to `thead` and when I do that it overflows the div no matter if I have `overflow-x: auto` set for `#table`